# How to ask a question that is close to a duplicate avoiding "closed as a duplicate"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

How do I ask a question that is close to a duplicate avoiding "closed as a duplicate", including the usual downvotes?

Current example: [Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50304263/4142984)

I have kind of the same problem, but the answers don't work for me.

Much may have changed since the question and answers, and, regrettably, it feels quite common that the same age-old bug is reborn repeatedly, out of different reasons, and with different cures.

As for the usual uncommented downvote (I would have expected more than one) and the general prospect of getting a useful answer (the original post has seen 20k visits) I deleted [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63548932/4142984).

Comment: Ask the question and explain in detail for each answer of the original what you have checked and why it doesn't apply for you.

Comment: Mind you, in the end it's a question that's likely to be closed by a different reason (or with a different dupe target). Without knowing more details, it doesn't seem like a question that will be useful for future visitors. (Note that the question you refer to has been closed as well).

Comment: @yivi that is exactly the reason why I didn't ask the question *again* but asked here. What you tell me is exactly what I have seen in the past. Once a question is asked, there always will be high-k dudes with no willingness to read *and understand* the question before closing it.

Comment: I don't know about that rant of yours. What I meant is that type of question you describe  generally _deserves_ closing. Of course, can't say more without actually looking at the question. But the "something is missing, not found, not defined, etc" type of questions are the vast majority of the time solved by the asker fiddling around with their setup. They are either unclear, of a result of a typo-like situation, or something like that. There are exceptions, but we can't tell if yours is the case. The fact that you point to a question that was closed by reason may be a red flag here.

Comment: @yivi "Of course, can't say more without actually looking at the question." Of course. Why don't you?

Comment: Did you post the question for us to look at?

Comment: Because you haven't posted it, and my clairvoyant powers are waning.

Comment: @takendarkk No, but with the link is a comment of mine where I (very brief) describe my problem.

Comment: @yivi "Because you haven't posted it" yes, that was on purpose. I didn't want more downgrades. Thre is a comment of mine to the original question I gave a link.

Comment: You posted a link to another question, that had **many** comments under it. You expected us to open all the comments and see if by chance you left a comment _there_ that was relevant to your question _here_? That's a bit much to expect, I believe. Three things: 1) your comment there does not address the post it is published under, so it's not really useful. 2) you could describe your hypothetical question here, on this meta-post. 3) judging from the details on that comment, the question you may want to ask may not do very well.

Comment: @BDL I did: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63548932/4142984 and now I will see the down-votes.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: You might want to add a screenshot showing what exactly your build path contains (especially the jdk version and so on). Other than that, the question looks fine to me (although not a Kotlin expert).

Comment: @yivi "You posted a link to another question, that had many comments under it." as of now, I count exactly nine, the posters clearly visible.

Comment: I'm not sure of your point there, really. 9 comments are  a lot of comments. You pointed to a question, you should expect other users to read the question. If you wanted anyone to read a specific comment (like yours, that is hidden by default because of the amount of comments), you should mention it. The place to mention this was on this question, not on further comments. I'm out of here, good luck!

Answer (score 6):

> How do I ask a question that is close to a duplicate avoiding "closed as a duplicate", including the usual downvotes?

1. Ask a non-duplicate question. It is for others who earned the privilege to vote for closing a question to decide whether it is duplicate or not. We cannot predict how your question will fare, should it be closed, or does it merit its own Q&A *until you post it*.
2. Ask a good question. Downvotes usually accompany questions with a lack of research, prior effort, too specific, or too broad ones. Asking an *obvious* duplicate or *insisting* on the post being sufficiently different because the environment is different (or something similar) is also likely to attract downvotes.

---

> there always will be high-k dudes with no willingness to read and understand the question

Sure there will be, and sometimes this is a valid complaint (in that case, take it here, and present your case as clear as possible *without accusations*). That said, try to understand the other side here: those who you call "high-k dudes" are mostly here for *at least* half a decade, and are usually very active in their respective areas. This also means they have been *working* in the area they frequent for at least that long (or more).

These people have a lot of experience, are likely to have duplicate targets bookmarked, and usually can see that *at its core* the question can be sufficiently answered by a canonical Q&A (or just a good enough one).

Finally, closing is a peer-review system where a question requires *3 people* with voting privileges to agree that it needs to be closed or a binding vote of a person with a *gold tag badge* (or a mod, but in general they refrain from doing so unless they happen to be experts in the matter).

---

> I didn't ask the question again but asked here

Don't try to optimize prematurely - post a question, respond to criticism, *politely* discuss its validity with those who closed it (if it is closed). Take it to a respective chat room if possible. If nothing helps, and you are still convinced it should be opened - post a question on Meta (again, I cannot stress it enough: be respectful of your peers and present the case as clearly as possible).

---

> and now I will see the down-votes

This is called [the meta-effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). When you post a link to a post on meta, you expose it to a higher level of scrutiny than you would normally get. And depending on the context of the conversation here *and* the quality of the post, it may be *either* a positive or negative effect (don't expect people not having a negative bias if you chose a defensive stance and calling them as you did in comments).

---

**Useful References**

1. [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)
2. [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

---

Disclosure: the answer was prepared before the question in discussion was posted

Comment: "respond to criticism," how can I do that when the reason for down-vote is not explained? Like the one for my actual question? My clairvoyant powers are waning, and from experience I know some that people don't need a reason.

Comment: @GyroGearloose - by criticism, I did not mean downvotes, but comments for clarification, closure reasons, etc. Downvotes are, alas, a necessary evil you can't directly address, sometimes they are unjustified, sometimes not. This is by no means a perfect system, but at the time is pretty much the best we've got. And we can't force people to leave feedback when downvoting, many have been hurt by doing that voluntarily...

Comment: @OlegValter: The downvote is not from me, but did you add what I suggested?

Comment: " but comments for clarification, closure reasons," I very well try to do so. Reasoned criticism is always  appreciated, but I rarely have seen some.

Comment: @BDL not exactly, as I can't reproduce easily (without setting up a new project) the missing kotlin library and I'm not really a friend of screenshots, much too easily there is some private or company confidential stuff there, too. I added the information as text.

Comment: @BDL another reason why I don't like screenshots is that it is not possible to do cut&paste. I worked for a company where it was essential to react on incidents really fast, and it always got me upset when the reporting party used screenshots instead of text.

Comment: @GyroGearloose There are ways to be extremely rude using just polite sentences and "as I can't reproduce easily (without setting up a new project)" is up top there.